# PIL paste image without blur

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to paste an image into a single coloured background using PIL but some blures and noises appear around pasted photo like this:

[image]

(Zoom photo to see noises. I think it is due from Antialiasing) But I want to paste with sharp boundaries like here :

[image]

I am using this codes for paste:

```
my_image.convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new("RGBA", (background_size), background_color)
background.paste( my_image, (coordinates), my_image )
background.save("result.jpg")
```

What sholud i do for pasting with sharp boundaries?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that first example really the output of your program? I am suspicious because it's a png, but your code saves a jpg.

Comment: actually first example is an jpg but i cropped it and the program that i cropped image saved it as png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jpg is a lossy format, so it may blur your image or add noise, in order to save memory. Use a lossless format like png instead:

```
background.save("result.png")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have changed my code background.save("result.png") but there is no difference.

Comment: @mnrl, Could you post a short self-contained runnable example program that exhibits your problem? Just looking at the four lines you posted, I can't see anything else wrong.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76369534/img.py This is the example code and this is the photo that i use : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76369534/a.png Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `background.save("result.png")` works! Forgive me I forgot the save changes in my source code :(